# 20 random numbers array from 0 to 10. How to count specific numbers in it?

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers, counting

I made this array but im struggling with counting the numbers. I could do it by using "IF" 10 times but it just seems wrong to me. Perhaps loop "for" would be the best to use here but i have no idea how to approach this.

```
import java.util.Random;


public class zadanie2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[];
        array = new int[20];


        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            Random rd = new Random();
            array[i] = rd.nextInt(10);
            System.out.print(array[i] + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to count occurrences of all random numbers? If yes, use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` and use the numbers as key and their occurrences as value.

Comment: Exactly. I want my program to make a list of them, someting like that:  
1 occured x times;  2 occured x times;  
etc...

Comment: Please don't create a new `Random` at each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is quick fix for you. Check following code.

```
    int inputArray[];
    inputArray = new int[20];
    Random rd = new Random();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> elementCountMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        inputArray[i] = rd.nextInt(10);
    }
    for (int i : inputArray) {
        if (elementCountMap.containsKey(i)) {
            elementCountMap.put(i, elementCountMap.get(i) + 1);
        } else {
            elementCountMap.put(i, 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Input Array : " + Arrays.toString(inputArray));
    System.out.println("Element Count : " + elementCountMap);
```

**Output :**

Input Array : [9, 7, 3, 0, 8, 6, 3, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 6, 5, 7, 1, 5]

Element Count : {0=1, 1=2, 2=2, 3=3, 5=2, 6=2, 7=4, 8=1, 9=3}

Hope this solution works.

Comment: Thanks but i need a GOOD while to understand that.... Like day or two. Do you know where i could find some decent information about HashMap?

Comment: Please don't create a new `Random` at each iteration.

Comment: You can check more decent information about HashMap from official site of oracle. link is [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: @MauricePerry I have updated my code so now new ```Random``` will not create on each iteration.

Comment: This works, but the second `for` loop is not necessary. Why loop through the thing twice if you can just do everything in the first loop? The array doesn't have to be completely filled to count the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing the occurrences per random number and in addition, you are creating a new `Random` in each iteration, which should not be done.

If you want to store the occurrences, then define a proper data structure for that, otherwise you won't be able to store them. I have used a `Map<Integer, Integer>`, see this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define a data structure that holds the random numbers and their count
    Map<Integer, Integer> valueOccurrences = new TreeMap<>();
    // define a range for the random numbers (here: between 1 and 10 inclusively)
    int minRan = 1;
    int maxRan = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        // create a new random number
        int ranNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minRan, maxRan + 1);
        // check if your data structure already contains that number as a key
        if (valueOccurrences.keySet().contains(ranNum)) {
            // if yes, then increment the currently stored count
            valueOccurrences.put(ranNum, valueOccurrences.get(ranNum) + 1);
        } else {
            // otherwise create a new entry with that number and an occurrence of 1 time
            valueOccurrences.put(ranNum, 1);
        }
    }

    // print the results
    valueOccurrences.forEach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println(key + " occurred " + value + " times");
    });
}
```

As an alternative, you can use a `Random`, but use one instance for all iterations:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define a data structure that holds the random numbers and their count
    Map<Integer, Integer> valueOccurrences = new TreeMap<>();
    // create a Random once to be used in all iteration steps
    Random random = new Random(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        // create a new random number
        int ranNum = random.nextInt();
        // check if your data structure already contains that number as a key
        if (valueOccurrences.keySet().contains(ranNum)) {
            // if yes, then increment the currently stored count
            valueOccurrences.put(ranNum, valueOccurrences.get(ranNum) + 1);
        } else {
            // otherwise create a new entry with that number and an occurrence of 1 time
            valueOccurrences.put(ranNum, 1);
        }
    }

    // print the results
    valueOccurrences.forEach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println(key + " occurred " + value + " times");
    });
}
```

Note that those examples do not create the same numbers in the same range.

Answer (score 0):

As @deHaar commented, you could use a `Map` to do that:

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class CountNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create array and Random instance
        int[] array = new int[20];
        Random rd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        //create Map to count numbers occurrences
        Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<>();

        //fill array with random numbers and count the
        //occurrences in one go...
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = rd.nextInt(10);

            //count inserted number
            counts.put(
                array[i],
                counts.containsKey(array[i]) ? counts.get(array[i]) + 1 : 1
            );
        }

        //print count result:
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int i : counts.keySet())
            System.out.println("The number " + i +
                    " was inserted " + counts.get(i) + " times.");
    }

}
```

This prints

```
The number 0 was inserted 1 times.
The number 1 was inserted 1 times.
The number 2 was inserted 3 times.
The number 4 was inserted 1 times.
The number 5 was inserted 1 times.
The number 6 was inserted 5 times.
The number 7 was inserted 3 times.
The number 8 was inserted 3 times.
The number 9 was inserted 2 times.
```

Comment: Thank you! This one seems easier to understand :) Could you recommend me some good sites to learn about HashMaps and TreeMap?

Comment: @santana011 Maybe [this](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/java-map-collection-tutorial-and-examples) site could help you?

Answer (score -1):

Since you did not state otherwise i would assume you just need to print the values:

```
    IntStream.range(0, 10)
          .forEach(n -> System.out.println(n + "->" + Arrays.stream(array)
                                                            .filter(i -> i == n)
                                                            .count()));
```